# please help to understand the solution of olympiad number theory from aops

Tags: number-theory

Problem:
Let
$$
D=d_{1} d_{2} d_{3} d_{4} d_{5} d_{6} d_{7} d_{8} d_{9}
$$
be a nine-digit positive integer (each digit not necessarily distinct). Consider
$$
E=e_{1} e_{2} e_{3} e_{4} e_{5} e_{6} e_{7} e_{8} e_{9}
$$
another nine-digit positive integer with the property that each digit $e_{i}$ when substituted for $d_{i}$ makes the modified D divisible by 7 . Let $F=f_{1} f_{2} f_{3} f_{4} f_{5} f_{6} f_{7} f_{8} f_{9}$ be a third nine-digit positive integer with the same relation to $\mathrm{E}$ as $\mathrm{E}$ has to $\mathrm{D}$.
Prove that every $d_{i}-f_{i}$ is divisible by 7 .

Solution:
Any positive integer $D=d_{1} d_{2} d_{3} d_{4} d_{5} d_{6} d_{7} d_{8} d_{9}$ can be expressed $\left(10^{8}\right) d_{1}+\left(10^{7}\right) d_{2}+\ldots\left(10^{0}\right) d_{9}$.
Since $10=3 \bmod 7$, and since it holds that if a=b mod $\mathbf{c}$ then $a^{n}=b^{n}$ mod $\mathbf{c}$, then $\mathrm{D}$ can be expressed much more simply mod 7; that is, $D=2 d_{1}+3 d_{2}+1 d_{3}-2 d_{4}-3 d_{5}-d_{6}+2 d_{7}+3 d_{8}+d_{9}=\mathbf{x} \bmod 7$
Each number in E must make the modified D equal $0 \bmod 7$, so for each $d_{i}, e_{i}=\frac{x+7 k}{c}-d_{i}$, where $c$ is the coefficient of $d_{i}$ and $k$ is an element of $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. The patient reader should feel free to verify that this makes $\mathbf{D}=0 \bmod 7$.
In terms of $d_{i}$ terms, then, we find each $c_{i} e_{i}=x-c_{i} d_{i}+7 k$.
Then $E=2 e_{1}+3 e_{2}+1 e_{3}-2 e_{4}-3 e_{5}-e_{6}+2 e_{7}+3 e_{8}+e_{9} \bmod 7$ can be expressed $E=\left(x-2 d_{1}\right)+\left(x-3 d_{2}\right)+\left(x-d_{3}\right)+\ldots+\left(x-d_{9}\right)=(9 x)-D \bmod 7=(9 \mathrm{x})-\mathrm{x}=8 \mathrm{x}=\mathrm{x}$ mod 7 . (Note that the $7 \mathrm{~s}$, which do not change the mod value, have been eliminated.)
Each number in $\mathrm{F}$ must make the modified $\mathrm{E}$ equal 0 mod 7, so for each $e_{i}, f_{i}=\frac{x+7 k_{2}}{c_{i}}-e_{i}=\frac{x+7 k_{2}}{c_{i}}-\left(\frac{x+7 k_{1}}{c_{i}}-d_{i}\right)$.
By design and selection of $k$, all $\left(f_{i}\right)$ are integers, and $d_{i}-f_{i}$ is always an integer because it is the difference of two integers.
$d_{i}-f_{i}=\frac{7 k_{2}-7 k_{1}}{c_{i}}$
$c_{i}$ is a member of the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Since no $c_{i}$ divides 7,7 may be factored and $7 \frac{k_{2}-k_{1}}{c_{i}}=d_{i}-f_{i}$ is the product of two integers.
Let $A=\frac{k_{2}-k_{1}}{c_{i}}$ then $d_{i}-f_{i}=7 \mathrm{~A} \bmod 7=0 \bmod 7$ for all $\left(d_{i}, f_{i}\right)$, QED.

*** I dont understand the line given in solution

Each number in E must make the modified $\mathrm{D}$ equal $0 \bmod 7$, so for each $d_{i} e_{i}=\frac{x+7 k}{c}-d_{i}$, where $c$ is the coefficient of $d_{i}$ and $k$ is an element of $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. The patient reader should feel free to verify that this makes $D=0 \bmod 7$.

please help to understand this.

Comment: When each $e_i$ is substituted for $d_i$, does that not just make $D$? How is it "modified"? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AbidAfiq Please include a link to the AoPS solution you're referring to.

Comment: @Arthur What is meant is that if D is modified by replacing any single digit by the corresponding digit of E then the new D is divisible by 7.